# Why does 2nd JS async function call wait for 1st to finish?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was under the impression that a call to an async function would not be blocking unless the await keyword is used. However for the following code:

EDIT: I am editing the example to better illustrate my question.

```
function sum1Through(n) {
    console.log('Starting computation for ' + n);
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      result += i;
    }
    console.log('Finished computation for ' + n);
    return result;
}

function asyncSum1Through(n) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(sum1Through(n));
        }, 0);
    });
}

asyncSum1Through(1000000000);
asyncSum1Through(2);
sum1Through(3);
```

The order of output is:

```
Starting computation for 3
Finished computation for 3
Starting computation for 1000000000
Finished computation for 1000000000
Starting computation for 2
Finished computation for 2
```

Why is the 2nd call blocked until the 1st call completes but the 3rd call is not?

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your endpoint is `console.log()` then obviously *"all of your functions"* are asynchronous. Not only for one reason but two.

1. In the `asyncSum1Through()` function the `console.log()` instructions are invoked within `setTimeout`'s callback which makes them asynchronously invoked.
2. Even in `sum1Through(3)` function `console.log()` is by default invoked asynchronously but this is not our concern here.

So the output is very "as expected". Whereas the last instruction; namely... `sum1Through(3);` which happens to be synchronous up until `console.log()`, comes out first (since `console.log()` registers into the event queue first) and then the others follow as in the order they have entered into the event queue.

In fact it could have been more convoluted if you hadn't mixed in `setTimeout()` into your promises but that's totally another topic called microtasks.

Note : Oh..! If your question is; amongst the two asnc functions why the second waits for the first one to finish although the second one would take much less time to run? Then you should understand that asynchronous tasks does not have any privilage on the CPU work currently being consumed by the CPU thread. JS is a single threaded language and any task gets the right to render first has to finish first before the next. Asynchronicity in JS is meant tasks grant priority when other are waiting idle for an IO action which do not own the CPU thread JS running on.

Answer (score 0):

Using an async function doesn't mean that it will be executed "asynchronously". What it offers is that using the await it can be paused and wait for something.

[Async Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> An async function can contain an await expression, that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.

Answer (score 0):

All the code in your function is synchronous and runs immediately, before the call returns the promise. You would need to actually `await` something to have the code after the `await` run later.

Async functions are not starting a thread or running anything in parallel, and they cannot block their caller either. They just provide a simple syntax to write sequential code with promises.